# How can we pass list object from jsp to struts2 action?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm facing one issue in Struts2, Please find below information.

Java Code:

```
public class Employ{
  int empNo;
  String empName;
}

class EmployAction{
  List<Employ> empList=new ArrayList<Employ>();
  int eno;
  String ename;
}

<s:iterator value="empList">
<s:textfield name="eno" value="%{empNo}"/>
<s:textfield name="eName" value="%{empName}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

First I'm doing search operation and getting all employs list and iterating in JSP.

Whenever I'm submitting form this `empList` object is not passing to Action class. I want this List Object for some other processing.

How can i pass this list object to Action class? Note: Here I'm not using any of List Object fields as Named parameters in fields.

Comment: But not sure, why it is low quality one.

Comment: Because list is a collection which is in java.util package. How can HTML be aware of it? From website we can send everything in the form tag. which sends then as post or get variables which are strings only. This is just a basic concept. You can send array of strings not the collection List from html.

Comment: My self did some investigation and fixed this issue. for every iteration i'm passing data to array List and working fine. I spent lot of time on this, This fix might be help full some other persons

Comment: This is not low quality one, as per my understanding. Sometimes requirements different and not always same

Comment: You did great work... sorry for rating your question as low quality one. +1 to your answer....You taught me a lesson today...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long investigation found solution and fixed this issue. 
This solution might be helpful to anyone else.

```
<s:iterator value="empList" status="emp">
    <s:textfield name="eno" value="%{empNo}"/>
    <s:textfield name="eName" value="%{empName}"/>
    <s:hidden name="empList[%{#emp.index}].eno" value=%{empNo}/>
    <s:hidden name="empList[%{#emp.index}].ename" value=%{empName}/>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 2):

empList object will be not passed. Struts2 will pass your selected form values to your action class.

If you want to use that empList object to action class,just put that empList object to Session  .You can retrive value of emplist object from session in your action class and can process it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that Ravi gave is correct, but it can be improved
no need for hidden value
you can give the name of the field like what you gave in hidden

```
<s:iterator value="empList" status="emp">
    <s:textfield name="empList[%{#emp.index}].eno" value="%{empNo}"/>
    <s:textfield name="empList[%{#emp.index}].ename" value="%{empName}"/>
</s:iterator>
```